# Slow loading of website on specific computer (stalling) occasionally

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer

I have a problem with slow loading of a website, the problem is only on a specific computer (Windows8), and only in chrome and IE, in Firefox the problem does not arise. We have several other computers (windows7/8/8.1) using the same website without the problem.

Sometimes at random the loading of the page is very slow (several minutes), and the debug console in chrome says "stalled" (in the "waterfall" view with loadtimes), and there is nothing to see in the webserver log on the server for that specific request.

In the chrome eventlog I can see this:

```
t=327413 [st=     2]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=327413 [st=     2]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=148474]
t=327413 [st=     2]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=148473]
                            --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
t=475886 [st=148475]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_RESTART_AFTER_ERROR
                            --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
t=475887 [st=148476]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t=475887 [st=148476]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=36]
t=475923 [st=148512]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
```

Comment: Have you done any hardware troubleshooting so we can rule out a software issue?

Comment: I turned out to be a software Issue, but that specific issue was only on that machine, so we can't rule out hardware entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to some antivirus/"internet protectinator" software that intercepted the connections, I no longer have acces to the machine/company but it was solved by disabling/uninstalling the software in question.